# change cross Browser Scroll bar ( css/ jquery)

Tags: jquery, css, html, cross-browser, styles

How can i change the browser scroll bar using css. I want to work it cross browser.[image]

i found the same as this questions in stackoverflow. but that answer not work for me. so i ask this..

Answer (score 1):

For IE and Opera:

```
body{
  scrollbar-face-color:;
  scrollbar-shadow-color:;
  scrollbar-highlight-color:;
  scrollbar-3dlight-color:;
  scrollbar-darkshadow-color:;
  scrollbar-track-color:;
  scrollbar-arrow-color:;
}
```

For Chrome and Safari, prefix the following with ::-webkit- and you're all set

```
scrollbar
scrollbar-button
scrollbar-track
scrollbar-track-piece
scrollbar-thumb
scrollbar-corner
resize
```

So for instance, you could have `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background:white;}` which, for IE and Opera, would be `body {scrollbar-face-color:white;}`

I don't know about Firefox, though.

Answer (score 0):

there are some plugins with jquery like perfect-scrollbar that makes custom scrollbar and change the styles. but if you want to use css to style scrollbar